# Surrounding a latex equation in vim

Tags: vim, latex, surround

I use vim (and the vim latex-suite) to edit latex documents. Something that occurs frequently is the need to change an inline equation into a displayed equation, as follows.  I start with:

```
The most important equation is \(f(x)=x^2,\) but most disagree.
```

and end with:

```
The most important equation is 
  \begin{equation*}
    f(x)=x^2,
    \end{equation*}
  but most disagree.
```

With the cursor on the "=" I'm happy to call a function to achieve the result, and I can probably figure out how to edit the indentation and spacing on my own, so it would be sufficient to output

```
The most important equation is 
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=x^2,
\end{equation*}
but most disagree.
```

Ideally, a function that works in the opposite direction (displayed equation to inline equation) would be great too, but first things first.  FWIW, I'm using the surround.vim plugin, which seems great for surrounding text in \( \), but I'm not sure if it can be used to detect/highlight a latex equation.  It seems to have this feature for HTML tags, but I haven't seen it implemented for latex.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**[EDIT:]**

To clarify what I'm looking for, I'd say it's whether or not surround.vim can be used for custom asymmetric quote/bracket detection.  Here's what I know how to do.  In my ~/.vimrc file, I have the line

```
autocmd FileType tex let b:surround_101 = "\\(\r\\)"
```

Then when I'm editing a tex file and I have the following:

```
This is a $word in$ a some text.
            [ ]
```

I can type in normal mode:

```
cs$e
```

and I get

```
This is a \(word in\) a some text.
         [ ]
```

Similarly, if I have

```
This is a <p>word in</p> a some text.
              [ ]
```

I can type in normal mode:

```
cste
```

and I get

```
This is a \(word in\) a some text.
         [ ]
```

What I'd like to do is go from this:

```
This is a \(word in\) a some text.
             [ ]
```

to this:

```
This is a \foo word in \bar a some text.
         [ ]
```

I'd like to know if this is possible with surround.vim.  For example, on this:

```
This is a \(word in\) a some text.
             [ ]
```

I tried

```
cse$
```

but that didn't change \(word in\) to $word in$ as I had hoped.  If this is not possible to do with surround.vim, it would be a shame, since it already has the exact functionality for HTML tags that I want for latex equations, so it seems like I'd have to recode the same functionality for latex equations from scratch.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Comment: Yes, surround.vim can do this; check out `:help surround-customizing`. Surround doesn't detect (latex equations or whatever); you choose the type of surrounding by typing the corresponding _replacement_ after `ys`.

Comment: I edited my post to clarify my question, and give an example of what I've tried.

Answer (score 2):

If you use vimtex rather than vim-latex-suite, I think it has what you're looking for. `cse` for change surrounding environment will ask you to input an environment name and then change the surrounding `$`'s to `\begin{...} \end{...}`, and it looks pretty straightforward to create custom bindings for commonly used environments. It can also toggle delimiters from `( )` to `\left( \right)`, instantly toggle between `equation` and `equation*` environments.

Answer (score 0):

You can make *surround.vim* enclose text with `\foo` ... `\bar` with this:

```
let b:surround_102 = "\\foo \r \\bar"
```

Now, `ys2wf` will surround the next `2` `w`ords; `f` is the (arbitrarily) chosen replacement symbol and corresponds to `:echo char2nr('f')` => `102`.

This is documented under `:help surround-customizing`. It defines a custom *replacement*. In order to convert `\(...\)` to `\foo ... \bar` (or vice versa), you also would have to define a custom *target* (cp. `:help surround-targets`). Unfortunately, that currently isn't supported by the plugin; only a fixed set of targets is supported, the tags are implemented as a special case inside the plugin. At least for literal replacements as in this case, I see no reason why the plugin couldn't also support those. Oh look, someone already [opened an issue](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/194) for exactly this!

There are also alternative plugins like [vim-sandwich](https://github.com/machakann/vim-sandwich). I have only briefly looked at that plugin so far, but it seems to have far superior customizability, so it might work there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that recent versions of surround.vim provide a `\` replace target, such that

```
yss\equation*<CR>
```

surrounds the line in an equation environment. `l` is a synonym.